# How to create a subdomain at freenom.com?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I created a domain at freenom.com 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/an4tz.jpg
which points to my app at Digital ocean droplet.
and next day I created this domain I tested and it works.
that domain is 1) at printscreen above.

Now I want to create several subdomains, as I know that is possible to make:

```
site.com - domain
dev1.site.com, dev2.site.com - subdomains
```

But I do not know what must be entered in fields 2) and 3) ?

When I tried as at printscreen above I got error :

```
Error occured: Invalid value in dnsrecord
```

Which are valid values ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A domain name (for use as websites etc.) should point at an IP address. There are several kinds of DNS records. Records for pointing at IP addresses are A records, as you have in 1). Other kinds are MX records for mail servers, for example.

If you want to create a subdomain, you want to create another A record, so simply choose A for the "type" field.

Alternatively, if the IP is the same as an existing record, use a CNAME record which points to another record, e.g.

```
Name           Type    TTL    Target
dev1.site.com  CNAME   14440  site.com
```

This says that dev1.site.com should use the same record(s) as site.com, so if you ever update the A record of site.com, it will automatically apply to all subdomains too.

Answer (score 3):

I found the way to
add two A  record

```
A  www.dev2   IP (same ip of your original website)
A  dev2       IP (same ip of your original website)
```

Answer (score 2):

Setup 2 subdomains on the Freenom DNS:

[image: Freenom DNS]

Answer (score 1):

The CNAME record type does not accept a IP number.

For the subdomains, use a CNAME, but make the target the @ sign, which represents the root domain.

To be clear, this will make both subdomains point to the IP address of the A record you specified for the root domain.

If you want the subdomains to point to a different IP, then use an A record instead of a CNAME record.

Comment: Is "@" something specific to freenom (which I have never used…)?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/83874/whats-the-meaning-of-in-a-dns-zone-file