# How do I add a subdomain in Freenom

Tags: dns, ip, subdomain

I am trying to add a subdomain to my Minecraft server that displays a map of the world. My server is up and running just fine on my domain from the default settings. I am trying to add a subdomain under map.address.tk. When I go to the manage domain box, I put in map.address.tk with TTL 300 and the IP:8100 in the IP box. When I save it says Error occured: Invalid value in dnsrecord. How do I do this?

Comment: I think it must be the answer for your question: [Click here to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810608/how-to-create-a-subdomain-at-freenom-com#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20create,points%20to%20another%20record%2C%20e.g.)

Comment: I have seen that thread and it doesn't work because when I add the information in that format it still says Error occured: Invalid value in dnsrecord. Thanks anyway.